# How to show content of a nested table with a cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, nested-table

I want to show the content of a nested table using a cursor. I've try the following but it does not work. The arguments in the "put_line" are not correct but I don't know why.

```
create or replace type toys_t as table of varchar2(40);

create or replace type kid_t as object (name varchar2(10), toys toys_t);

create table kid of kid_t nested table toys store as table_toys;

insert into kid values('Bob', toys_t('truck','ball','doll'));

select t.* from kid k, table(k.toys) t where k.name = 'Bob';


declare

cursor cursor_table is
   select t.* from kid k, table(k.toys) t where k.name = 'Bob';

begin

   for i in cursor_table loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
   end loop;

end;
```

It's very simple. A kid have a name and a list of toys and I want to show the toys but not from a "select" but a cursor.

Thanks from your help.

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the column name in the loop

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    cursor cursor_table is
  3     select t.* from kid k, table(k.toys) t where k.name = 'Bob';
  4  begin
  5     for i in cursor_table loop
  6        dbms_output.put_line(i.column_value);
  7     end loop;
  8* end;
SQL> /
truck
ball
doll

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and fast reply.